# Row copy/paste functionality in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on a C# Windows application and would like to copy a row in a DataGridView before pasting it into a new row. How I can achieve this? I am using .NET Framework 3.5.

Can you please provide me with some ideas or some code that would indicate how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

I have found a [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e9cee429-5f36-4073-85b4-d16c1708ee1e/) that contains code to paste values from clipboard into DataGridView.

> I was googling how to paste to
>   DataGridView in C# from clipboard, an
>   info, copied from Excel, and didn't
>   find full answer. Collected couple of
>   threads from forums and came up with
>   this answer, hope it will make
>   someones life easier. You dont have to
>   understand the code just copy and
>   paste

Below is a bit modified version. Beyond small refactoring I forbid paste into ReadOnly cells.

Usage example:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ClipboardUtils.OnDataGridViewPaste(sender, e);
}
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Commons
{
    public class ClipboardUtils
    {
        public static void OnDataGridViewPaste(object grid, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V))
            {
                PasteTSV((DataGridView)grid);
            }
        }

        public static void PasteTSV(DataGridView grid)
        {
            char[] rowSplitter = { '\r', '\n' };
            char[] columnSplitter = { '\t' };

            // Get the text from clipboard
            IDataObject dataInClipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            string stringInClipboard = (string)dataInClipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

            // Split it into lines
            string[] rowsInClipboard = stringInClipboard.Split(rowSplitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // Get the row and column of selected cell in grid
            int r = grid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            int c = grid.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;

            // Add rows into grid to fit clipboard lines
            if (grid.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length))
            {
                grid.Rows.Add(r + rowsInClipboard.Length - grid.Rows.Count);
            }

            // Loop through the lines, split them into cells and place the values in the corresponding cell.
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rowsInClipboard.Length; iRow++)
            {
                // Split row into cell values
                string[] valuesInRow = rowsInClipboard[iRow].Split(columnSplitter);

                // Cycle through cell values
                for (int iCol = 0; iCol < valuesInRow.Length; iCol++)
                {

                    // Assign cell value, only if it within columns of the grid
                    if (grid.ColumnCount - 1 >= c + iCol)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCell cell = grid.Rows[r + iRow].Cells[c + iCol];

                        if (!cell.ReadOnly)
                        {
                            cell.Value = valuesInRow[iCol];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice code. Not ready for prime time but most of the way there. I used it in a personal project and works as long as you slowly let up the 'v' in ctrl+v first, and grid must be in EditMode of EditOnKeystrokeOrF2

Answer (score 2):

DataGridViewRow class has a .Clone method which will clone the current row that it holds.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone.aspx) for more info

Comment: I checked it. But after copying data when i paste it into new rowof a gridview. It doesn't paste the data of the previous row while when i do paste in a single textbox..it occurs.

I just copy paste msdn code function after the function of DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Copy one row to another? Why simply not go for it like this

```
public DataGridViewRow CloneWithValues(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    DataGridViewRow clonedRow = (DataGridViewRow)row.Clone();
    for (Int32 index = 0; index < row.Cells.Count; index++)
    {
        clonedRow.Cells[index].Value = row.Cells[index].Value;
    }
    return clonedRow;
}
```

Also you can refer to: http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/06/copying-datagridviewrow-to-another.html

Hope this helps! :}

Answer (score 0):

> Below is my modified version of ***alex2k8*** answer this will work for bound datagridview.

here is the unmodified version

```
' Add rows into grid to fit clipboard lines
        if (grid.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length))
        {
            grid.Rows.Add(r + rowsInClipboard.Length - grid.Rows.Count);
        }
```

here is my modification happen hope someone got helped here dt is a datatable

```
    ' Add rows into grid to fit clipboard lines
    If grid.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length) Then
        Dim workRow As DataRow
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To (r + rowsInClipboard.Length - grid.Rows.Count)
            workRow = dt.NewRow()
            workRow(0) = ""

            dt.Rows.Add(workRow)
        Next
    End If
```

> NOTE: the code is in vb.net use http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert it back to c#

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers here but ended up having to something different due to by DataGridView being databound and the fact i am hiding certain rows which messes up iteration on row index. This copies the current selected row and adds it to the datatable. Hope it helps.

```
    private void BtnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow drToAdd = CopyDatagridValues(dataGridView1.CurrentRow);
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(drToAdd.ItemArray);
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();
    }


    public DataRow CopyDatagridValues(DataGridViewRow row)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        DataRow rows = dataTable.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index];

        return rows;
    }
```